# Unable to use bootstrap-datepicker on cloned rows. Value always stay on first date field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I found this issue when trying to clone a row using bootstrap-datepicker and bootstrap.

Steps to reproduce: 
1. Upon selecting the first input date(id_form-0-expense_date_item) user is able to select the date.
2. Adding another row and selecting second input date user is shown again with the datepicker however when date is select value goes to the first input field. id_form-0-expense_date_item

I am able to clone rows but calendar date stays always on the first field (id_form-0-expense_date_item).
When using jQuery UI 1.10.3 it works fine.

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uoyzbwro/9/

```
<table id="id_forms_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
         <th scope="col">Property name</th>
         <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
         <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="form-0-row" class="dynamic-form">
         <td> 
   <input class="datepicker" id="id_form-0-expense_date_item" name="form-0-expense_date_item" type="text" />
         </td>
         <td> Column </td>
         <td> Contains </td>
         <td>
            <a id="remove-form-0-row" href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-row">delete row</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div>
<button>Add Row</button>
  </div>
```

===

```
<!--

 $(function() {
     // datepicker plugin
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         // You can put more options here.
                     autoclose: true,
            startDate: new Date()
     });

 })

function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, index){
     var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
     var replacement = prefix + '-' + index;
     if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));    
     if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
     if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);    

}

var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
    //Destroy datepickers
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    myTr = $("#id_forms_table tbody tr:first").clone(true).appendTo("table");
    //Remove classes datepickers
    //myTr.removeClass('hasDatepicker').find("input");
    updateElementIndex(myTr, 'form', 1); 
    myTr.removeClass('hasDatepicker').find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
            'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
            'value': ''
        });
    });
    //myTr.find('input[id^="datep"]').addClass("mydatepickers");
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    i++;
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;
});



 $(function() {
     // datepicker plugin
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         // You can put more options here.
                     autoclose: true,
            startDate: new Date()
     });

 })


 //-->
```

Comment: what does "stays always on the same field" mean? When I go to the fiddle - I don't know what I'm supposed to be typing in and what is expected to happen when I do...

Comment: 1) Don't tell me in the comments.  This stuff should be part of your question :) please edit your question and add the information there - and anything else you can think of that might be related ;)

Comment: don't use clone(true) and then reintialize datepicker on new row

Comment: 2) I already made it clear that "It stays always on the same field" does not make enough sense... please explain it in different words - be more complete in your explanation.. especially take note of explaining what "it" is you should always avoid using "it" with other people - be specific), also what it means to be "on the same field"... what field is that? same field as what?

Comment: Ignore the code... what should the user see when they type something into the field? what should they type in. What should they click on... what should they see when they do that? I don't want to *have* to figure out what you're *trying* to do with your code.... you should just tell me what the expected behaviour is :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch charlietfl. You were right. I've changed clone(true) to false and have reinitialized datepicker on the new row.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by charlietfl I've changed clone(true) to false and have reinitialized datepicker on the new row as seen below.

http://jsfiddle.net/uoyzbwro/11/

```
 $(function() {
     // datepicker plugin
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         // You can put more options here.
                     autoclose: true,
     });

 })

function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, index){
     var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
     var replacement = prefix + '-' + index;
     if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));    
     if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
     if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);    

}

var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
    //Destroy datepickers
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    myTr = $("#id_forms_table tbody tr:first").clone(false).appendTo("table");
    //Remove classes datepickers
    //myTr.removeClass('hasDatepicker').find("input");
    updateElementIndex(myTr, 'form', 1); 
    myTr.removeClass('datepicker').find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
            'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
            'value': ''
        });
    });
    //myTr.find('input[id^="datep"]').addClass("mydatepickers");
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         // You can put more options here.
                     autoclose: true,
     });
    i++;
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;
});



 $(function() {
     // datepicker plugin
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         // You can put more options here.
                     autoclose: true,
     });

 })
```